# Can we add gif in icon of chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons

When request is sent to API to load some data, can we add some loading gif as icon ?
Something like this:

```
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
        path : "../img/loading.gif"
      });
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/#icon), you can use a gif static image, but not a gif animation.

Comment: you can build an animation changing the icon image more times and quickly.
take this extension as inspiration: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/worldwide-radio/ofncbjjbfchlegacifnndkkbdoaedcof

Comment: @Robbi For an animated icon, the documentation recommends using `canvas`.

Comment: @Iván Nokonoko
Canvas is practically necessary if you want to make a dynamic (not predetermined) animation. If the animation is always the same (like a gif image) you can approach the problem by changing the frames (previously extrapolated) of a gif in succession.
The author of the extension I suggest uses this method very ingeniously